# Shake effects on form when information are incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, forms, shake

I want to have a form shake effect when typed information like login or password are incorrect.

http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/form_shake_on_invalid_entry/login.html < This is the effect that I want.

So I got the login code (login.php):

```
<?php

session_start();
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'xyz');
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    if(empty($_POST["login"])  ||   empty($_POST["passwd"])){
        header("location: index.php");

    }else{
        $username=$_POST["login"];
        $password=$_POST["passwd"];

    $username=stripslashes($username);
    $password=stripslashes($password);
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);

    $password=md5($password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM account WHERE login= '$username' and passwd= 
    '$password'";   


    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $_SESSION['idUzyt'] = $row['ID'];
        header("location: index.php");
    }else{
        header("location: zaloguj.php");
    }
  }
}


?>
```

And the login form code on page:

```
<?php
      echo 
        '<div><a href="index.php"><img style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:5% 0 0"; src="images/img_01.svg" /></a></div>

        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="login-form" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" />
                    <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" /> 
        <button>LOG IN</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>';          

?>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Its in the source of the linked site: http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/form_shake_on_invalid_entry/script.js - `$( "#login" ).effect( "shake" );`

Comment: Where I need to put that line in my code?